# Blocked insecure content chrome

Tags: google-chrome, load-balancing, haproxy

I am working with haproxy to configure ssl. in `ha.cfg` i am writing

```
frontend https
    bind    *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/ssl.key/myserver.crt 
    acl hari path_beg /customers
    acl css path_beg /assets
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
    use_backend appointpress_app if hari
    use_backend appointpress_app if css
    default_backend appointpress_site
```

Everything is fine in `Firefox` but in `Chrome` some JS and CSS are not being loaded. In console I am getting error :

```
[blocked] The page https://mydomain.com ran insecure content from http://mydomain.com/css/mycss.css
```

Why I am getting such error ad how I can come out of this problem. Am I missing something in haproxy config

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your assets and objects being loaded should all come from SSL.  Normally what is happening here is that you are calling something like a script or css file that is pointing to http rather than https.

Your best bet is to load all resources and assets using schemeless urls `src="//somedomain.com/asset.css"` for example.